# Connecting ado.net Entity data model to postgresql database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm new to C#, ado.net and visual studio 2012, just to make that clear from the beginning.

I'm trying to connect an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to a postgresql database. 

I tell VS to 'generate mdoel from database' and click to make a new connection. Postgresql is not listed as an alternative data source (I can only see different microsoft mysql sources).
I did download the [npsql](http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000140) .dlls and put them in the projects\ folder. I then added them by PROJECT->Add Reference->browse, check them and press ok.

Postgresql does still not appear as an alternative when I try to make a new connection.

In advance, thanks!

Comment: I'm able to add the database through  VIEW->Server Explorer-> Data Connections right-click-> Add Connection and then add an ODBC data source. But after doing this, it still does not show up when creating a new entity model.

Comment: Please post your code.  It will make answering this MUCH simpler.

Comment: There's is no code. Also, I found a [solution](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/articles/tutorial_ef.html). Its not free, but it is something atleast.